# Erro ao exportar o data.frame para o Excel

Tags: r, data.frame

Estou tentando exportar um data.frame para o Excel, mas o R apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Error in .jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook") :    Java
>   Exception .jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook")new("jobjRef",
>   jobj = , jclass =
>   "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError")

O comando que gera o erro acima é

```
write.xlsx(base_eng, "base_eng.xlsx")
```

Comment: usa o pacote `writexl` no lugar. Pacotes que tem dependência de Java costumam dar muito problema.

Comment: `writexl::write_xlsx(base_eng, "base_eng.xlsx")` deve funcionar depois de você instalar o pacote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode exportar para csv usando

```
write.table(variavel, "C:/arquivo.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Ou `write.csv`.